# Editing a value from a file in python

Tags: python

I am having some trouble getting a part of my code to read a value from a text file which then can be converted to an integer and then modified by adding a user input value, then input the new value into the file. This is for a simple inventory program that keeps track of certain items.
Example: 
User inputs 10 to be added to the number in the file. The number in the file is 231 so 10+231 = 241. 241 is the new number that is put in the file in place of the original number in the file. I have tried many different things and tried researching this topic, but no code I could come up with has worked. If it isn't apparent by now I am new to python. If anyone one can help it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What's have you tried so far?

Comment: Your question is currently very general, without examples of what you've tried or information about what problems you're observing. 

This page has some advice on how to frame your question in a way that will help others understand what advice you need: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Try editing your question to include an example of what you've tried and what errors you see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the steps that you need to take are

1. Open the file in read mode: `file = open("path/to/file", "r")`
2. Read the file to a python string: `file_str = file.read()`
3. Convert the string to an integer: `n = int(file_str)`
4. Add 10 and convert num: `num_str = str(n + 10)`
5. Close the file: `file.close()`
6. Reopen the file in write mode: `file = open("path/to/file", "w")`
7. Write the num string to the file: `file.write(num_str)`

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was trying to do, the only addition I made was asking the user for a number to add to the integer instead of always using 10.

Comment: Great! If you feel that I've answered your question, would you mind marking the answer as accepted?

Answer (score 0):

If your is 
1 2 3 4 5 6
7 8 9 10 11 12
....
....

then,go searching line by line and find the line number and index of your number.

`with open('data.txt') as f:
      content = f.readlines()`

`for x in range(len(content)):
     if '5' in content[x].split(' '):
        lno = x
        index = content[x].split(' ').index('5')`

So,now you got the index.Add the user input to the number and save it into the file as you have the line number and index.

Comment: I'm not trying to index anything, the file only contains a single value and I want to use an operator on that value and then replace the old value with the new value, but thank you this may come in handy later down the road with my program.

Comment: There exists only one number in the file.You want to find the single number and add the user input and save it back to the same position?

Comment: @IneffableTruth .. your file contains only a single value? As in, it's a text file with just one number, and nothing else?

Comment: I know it seems very dumb, but the purpose was to help teach me some of the basics in python both converting strings and with files I just ran into a snag in trying to do so. I know I could have just set it as a variable with an assigned value, but this is an arbitrary project more for learning than anything else.